# My code causing infinite loop, can't see the bug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am working on a WordPress project, using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

However I am getting a crazy infinite loop from my code, so I've obviously messed things up somewhere, however after a good two hours looking at it I can't see the problem.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    // If the loop has posts
    if (have_posts()) :
        // For each post this page has
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            // Display the Flexible Content
            while(has_sub_field('add_row')):

                // If the content type is Tagline
                if(get_row_layout() == 'tagline'): ?>
                    <div class="row paddingBottom paddingTop">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h3 class="tagLine"><?php the_sub_field('tagline'); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                // If the content type is a Featured Image
                /*elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'featured_image' ): ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 textCenter">
                        <?php   
                            $attachment_id = get_sub_field('featured_image');
                            $size = "full-width"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    </div>
                <?php*/
                // If the content type is a horizontal rule
                elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'horizontal_rule' ) : ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php   
                // If the content type is Columns
                elseif ( get_row_layout() == 'columns' ):
                    // If there is at least one column section
                    if(get_sub_field('column')):
                        // For each column section
                        while(has_sub_field('column')): ?>
                            <div class="row paddingTop paddingBottom"> 

                                <?php
                                    if(get_sub_field('column_content_type')):
                                        $count_rows = 0;
                                        // Counting
                                        while(has_sub_field('column_content_type')):
                                            $count_rows++;
                                        endwhile;
                                        // Loop
                                        while(has_sub_field('column_content_type')): ?>
                                            <div class="
                                                <?php /*
                                                    if ( $count_rows == 1 ) :
                                                        echo "col-xs-12";
                                                    elseif ( $count_rows == 2 ) :
                                                        echo "col-xs-6";
                                                    elseif ( $count_rows == 3 ) :
                                                        echo "col-xs-6 col-sm-4";
                                                    elseif ( $count_rows == 4 ) :
                                                        echo "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4";
                                                    endif; */
                                                ?>
                                            "> <?php
                                                // Title
                                                if ( get_sub_field('title') ) : ?>
                                                    <h2 class="smallTitle"><?php the_sub_field('title');?></h2><?php
                                                endif;
                                                // Text Area
                                                if ( get_sub_field('text') ) :
                                                    the_sub_field('text');
                                                endif;
                                                // Link
                                                if ( get_sub_field('link') ) : ?>
                                                    <?php // eventually need to make it so you can change the link text ?>
                                                    <a class="textCenter" href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>">
                                                        More info
                                                    </a> <?php
                                                endif; ?>
                                            </div> <?php
                                        endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                ?>

                            </div>                      

                            <?php
                        endwhile; // end for each column section
                    endif; // end checking for at least one column section

                endif; // end checking content type is columns

            endwhile; // end flexible content

         endwhile; // end for each post
    endif; // end checking for at least one post
    ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Will the `while(has_sub_field('column_content_type'))` loops ever terminate? You're just incrementing a variable inside the loop.

Comment: There is an endwhile on line 87 to end that

Comment: ...Do you know how While loops work?

Comment: I thought you could end a while statement with endwhile, like an if statement

Comment: If you want to get out of a loop you use `break;`

Comment: No if you want to just get out of it...  Say you have a loop that if `while ($x < 6) { $x++; if ($x == 4) { break;}`  Normally that loop wouldn't end until `$x` is 6.  But since I added the if statement I can leave the loop at 4.  Bad example... but maybe you understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(has_sub_field('column_content_type')):
     $count_rows++;
endwhile;
```

That's your problem...  But it could be one of many based on what I'm seeing.  It looks like you think while loops work like if statements...  All you are doing in that loop is incrementing it over and over.  It will never end.

Comment: Ah right, I was under the impression you could end a while statement with endwhile, as per the docs (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/flexible-content/) how is best to end this while statement?

Comment: Why even have it in a while loop?  It is already within a nested loop.

Comment: I'm totally confused, sorry for being a noob, I'm not sure how else to do it

Comment: We were all new at some point, no worries.  I'm still kinda new to the whole PHP thing myself.  But hold up one sec.  I found a few more issues.  I'll edit my answer in a moment.

Comment: I really don't know where to begin..  Most of your loops will never end.  It isn't incrementing or changing any values that will cause it to be false.  Where did you get this code from?  I would honestly recommend learning some PHP before going any farther with this.  Not trying to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is 
`// Display the Flexible Content
        while(has_sub_field('add_row')):`
i think you need to use `if(){
// Code 
}`
instead of "while"

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I used the code as per your recommendation, but the infinite loop remains. Also I found this link which recommends using has_sub_field() advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/flexible-content